# How do I click on this link using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, href

I am on this website and I am trying to click on Batch search using the selenium webDriver: 
https://metlin.scripps.edu/landing_page.php?pgcontent=mainPage

The HTML code for the link is:

```
<a href="landing_page.php?pgcontent=batch_search" style="color:white; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px">Batch Search </a >
```

My attempted solution is:

```
driver3.findElement(By.linkText("Batch Search")).click();
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use css selectors, which would be:

```
String selector = "a[href=\"landing_page.php?pgcontent=batch_search\"]";
driver3.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector)).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

`linkText` is an exact match but there's an extra space character after "Batch Search" that's not present in your query so it won't match.

Either fix the search query or use `partialLinkText`.